# git add command not working with ionic project

Tags: node.js, git, github, ionic-framework

I put in git add . and got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B8VP.png) , have tried redoing and backtracking but nothing seems to work. (Note: very new to all of this)

Comment: Please add the text of your error into the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you called `sudo ionic start` instead of `ionic start`.

As said in the other answers, you could **change the permissions** of the files that you don't own, or, if you didn't modify or add nothing yet to the project, you could just  **delete your project directory and start over** without using 'sudo'

Comment: Thank you, I just ended up deleting it and redoing it as you said and now everything works.

Comment: @SaH happy to help! So if you consider this question solved, you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check who owns the git lock:

```
ls -la /Users/sh/Desktop/myapps/firstApp/.git/index.lock
```

Then change the owner to yourself.

```
sudo chown <yourusername>:<yourgroupname> /Users/sh/Desktop/myapps/firstApp/.git/index.lock
```

If you are still having issues, remove the file (you may need to sudo or kill git process first):

```
sudo rm -f .git/index.lock
```

Comment: Thank you,  but when I put in ls -la /Users/sh/Desktop/myapps/firstApp/.git/index.lock it came back with "ls: /Users/sh/Desktop/myapps/firstApp/.git/index.lock: No such file or directory"? Also how exactly would I change the owner to myself? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the folder and subfolder permission.

follow this tutorial 
http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/03/automatically-set-subfolders.html

give read & write permission to everyone and try again.